# Windows Phone cancelling Async tasks when pressing back button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, async-await

When I load a page in my app I fire off a series of `WebClient.DownloadStringAsync` requests.  These go out and perform json api calls.  I have noticed that if the user presses the back button before the app hits my `WebClient_StringCompleted` the task is still completed and I would rather it not to.  Is there a way to stop all async tasks using the `OnBackKeyPress` override?

UPDATE:

I ended up blending both of the below answers.  Here is my code I settled on:

```
 WebClient VideoDetails = new WebClient();
            id = parameter;
            VideoDetails.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(VideoDetails_StringCompleted);
            if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using (CancellationTokenRegistration ctr = cts.Token.Register(() => VideoDetails.CancelAsync()))
                {
                    VideoDetails.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.url.com/api/get_video_detail?id=" + VideoID));
                }
            }
```

cts is a class variable of type CancellationTokenSource

I can then fire off in my OnBackKeyPress override;

```
ct.Cancel();
```

This will cancel all WebClient's using the CancelAsync() method in the WebClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I've looked after some nice tutorials about CancellationToken and Progress Reporting, but for Windows 8 app. Check it out, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj651494.aspx) (2nd video is with CancellationToken to stop async work), I think it might help you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for the [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync Method (Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ms144202%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> You can use the [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.webclient.cancelasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method to cancel asynchronous operations
>   that have not completed.

Have you tried it?

You could use the [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) and use one of the overloads of the [GetAsync Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync.aspx) that takes a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) and use it to cancel all pending operations.

You can get the [HttpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) from **Windows Phone** on the the [HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package (Microsoft.Net.Http)](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http)

Comment: Your answer helped greatly as well thanks!  Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to up vote yet. ;)